# Need advice on maker/checker for Update Authorization

Tags: spring

I need some advice on data authorization similar to Auditing. The requirement is that every update action on the Business Entity should be authorized. The object graph is little complicated so we are unable to finalize wether to go with Triggers or Application level logging of changed values in some Queue and upon authorization we replace those values in actual recordset.
Challenger here is finding which values are changed in a particular entity, let say the entity under 
discussion is Customer which has several composition and aggregation relation further like CustomerGroup, MobileUser, Address, Accounts, Preferences etc. Also there are two types of Custoemr which is mapped using JPA inheritance. Now we need to find the set of values 
changed from UI and log it in some authorization table, then upon approval of that change another challenge is to replace the changed values in actual tables (data spans over multiple table in this scenario). Kindly suggest best industry approach for this use case.

Technologies Used: Spring 3.x, JPA 2 + Hibernate, Oracle 11g
NB: Its a scenario best known in the industry as maker/checker concept or 4 eye principal. But we need to follow standards here so need some advice.